# Laravel 4: run multiple update query in 1 request

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

is there any way to run multiple update queries in single connection in Laravel,

queries:

```
update users set score = score+130 where id = 12;
update users set score = score+10 where id = 10;
update users set score = score+10 where id = 14;
```

I tried: (not working)

```
DB::update("
    update users set score = score+130 where id = 12;
    update users set score = score+10 where id = 10;
    update users set score = score+10 where id = 14;
");
```

thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Your case can be resolved with two queries:

```php
DB::table('users')->where('id', 12)->increment('score', 130);
DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', [10, 14])->increment('score', 10);
```

Comment: so there is no way to run it in single connetion?

Comment: by default you have single DB connection.